# ¿Es correcto decir "Las crías las da a luz ya nacidas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sintaxis, animales

Buscando información sobre los **peripatos** he encontrado en este [blog](http://enciclopediadeanimalesvirtual.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/peripato-u-onicoforo.html) información interesante, pero me ha llamado la atención la frase:

> Las crías las da a luz ya nacidas, siendo blancas y valiendose por si misma desde el momento de haber nacido, ya que la madre no se pude hacer cargo de ellas.

La frase tiene de algún fallo de acentuacion y concordancia, pero ¿es correcta la parte inicial de "Las crías **las da a luz ya nacidas** ..."? ¿No es "dar a luz" hacer que nazcan? ¿O es una figura retórica válida para recalcar que no ponen huevos o algo así?

Answer (score 3):

Si buscas otras páginas que hablen de estos animales, verás que en muchas se hace referencia a lo mismo: las crías nacen "ya salidas del huevo", vivas y completas, pasado el período de feto o embrión.

Como digo, en otras páginas aparece lo mismo, así que aunque no me gusta mucho referenciarla, en el [artículo de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onychophora) aparece que pueden nacer de dos formas:

1. Crecer en un huevo dentro de la madre, eclosionando del huevo dentro de la madre, y entonces saliendo al exterior(**a esto debe referirse el blog probablemente: las crías nacen -de la madre- ya nacidas -del huevo-**).
2. De una forma vivípara normal, es decir, sin huevo, desarrollándose el feto, supongo, que no lo sé, en un órgano parecido o igual al útero de cualquier hembra vivípara.

Obviamente, si se lee sin contexto, en literal, es una redundancia, pero sabiendo que nacen antes de un huevo, es simplemente ahorrarse la referencia al dicho huevo.
Bien es cierto que confunde y "enrevesa" un poco la frase, pero bueno, se puede arreglar con un poco de investigación acerca del contexto...

Además, como apunta el compañero Jdamian en los comentarios, aunque el significado se entiende igual, la expresión [dar a luz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NkAteAU) se debería usar solo para los humanos; [parir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RwYmdsn) es una palabra más adecuada para el resto de los animales. Es lo mismo que usar *pata* en vez de *pierna*.
Quizás, utilizando dicha expresión el/la autor/a del blog quería enfatizar el echo del nacimiento vivíparo, o simplemente la usó de manera incorrecta... en cualquier caso, ciertamente es un uso incorrecto y está dentro del objeto de la pregunta, así que queda escrito.

Comment: Según el DRAE, ***[dar a luz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NkAteAU)*** solo se aplica a las mujeres, no al resto de animales. Sin embargo, **[parir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RwYmdsn)** sí se aplica a cualquier ***hembra de cualquier especie vivípara***

Comment: Cierto, aunque se entienda el significado, siendo estrictos eso también es incorrecto, lo añadiré a la respuesta.

Comment: @Jdamian y no sólo en el RAE, en otros de diccionarios se define como _alumbrar un bebé_ y un bebé es un ser humano (aunque he visto usarlo a veces con animales pero no creo que sea correcto)

Answer (score 2):

Hay que entender el *sentido* de la expresión en el contexto. Y creo que se entiende, es claro y no hay para qué ser tan quisquillosos.

Pero si vamos al *significado* de las palabras, no es tan simple la cosa. (Siempre es agradable buscarle la quinta pata al gato y a eso nos dedicamos con frecuencia en este sitio). Veamos lo que dice el DRAE:

> [**nacer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QBdrkiM)
>
> **1**. intr. Dicho de un ser vivo: Salir del vientre materno, del huevo o de la semilla.
>
> **[dar a luz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NkAteAU)**
>
> **1**. loc. verb. Dicho de una mujer: **parir**.
>
> **[parir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RwYmdsn)**
>
> **1**. intr. Dicho de una hembra de cualquier especie vivípara: Expeler en tiempo oportuno el feto que tenía concebido. U. t. c. tr.
>
> **2**. intr. **aovar**.
>
> **[aovar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=32H4rR4)**
>
> **1**. intr. Dicho de las aves y de otros animales: Poner huevos.

Considerando que "dar a luz" es una personificación cuando no hablamos de crías humanas, y dejando de lado las plantas, tenemos las siguientes posibilidades:

**Si el ser vivo es vivíparo:**

Dar a luz (expeler el feto) y nacer (salir del vientre materno) ocurren siempre al mismo tiempo. Son el mismo hecho. Entonces **no**, los vivíparos no pueden dar a luz crías nacidas.

**Si el ser vivo es ovíparo:**

Dar a luz (poner la hembra el huevo) no puede ocurrir antes de nacer (salir del huevo) porque, de hecho, si la cría ya salió del huevo ya no hay huevo que poner. Entonces **no**, los ovíparos no pueden dar a luz crías nacidas.

**Si el ser vivo es [ovovivíparo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovoviviparidad)**

La hembra pone un huevo y luego la cría nace (sale del huevo), pero esto ocurre *dentro* del cuerpo de la hembra. Posteriormente la hembra da a luz (expele el feto). Vale decir, los ovovivíparos **sí** dan a luz crías que habían nacido previamente.

(Nota: Mi postura inicial negaba la posibilidad de dar a luz crías nacidas, pero @Barbara aportó el caso de los ovovivíparos).

Comment: Pero entonces si es ovovivíparo https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovoviviparidad si sería posible: "El organismo pone huevos, pero estos permanecen dentro del cuerpo de la hembra hasta que el embrión está completamente desarrollado. La eclosión puede producirse inmediatamente antes del parto." En este caso la cría sale del huevo ("nace") dentro del cuerpo de la hembra, y al salir de ésta, la hembra "da a luz". O sea, que los ovovivíparos **si** pueden "dar a luz a crias nacidas", ¿no? ¿O lo he entendido mal?

Comment: Como en este video de youtube en que muestran como nace un camaleon : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylNV3IGklHY o crias de tiburones : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUx0c5U_Mno

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Nunca pensé que había una tercera posibilidad. Te sugiero responder tu propia pregunta, ya diste con toda la información necesaria.

Comment: No, la respuesta correcta y trabajada es la tuya, solo falta añadir a los ovovivíparos (en los que yo pensé al leerla) para que quede perfecta